# mapkit map view slide to glide to and zoom into effect?

Tags: ios, mapkit, core-location

I'm new to mapkit and are trying to add a "gliding/sliding and zoom into type transition effect" that I quite often see in these kind of map apps for the MkMapView.

For example I might be looking, navigating and zooming around a map through touch/pinch and zoom and then I click "go to my location" for example it would then glide/slide over and then zoom down into my location with a region/view size that I have set, like a transition effect I guess you could call it. 
How is this done? Is there a method for doing this or do you have to program that effect manually?

Currently I would press "Go to my location" button and it goes to my current location and the size is to what I want, but there is no sliding/gliding/zooming in transition type effect. 
Any help would be great

```
- (IBAction)zoomToCurrentLocation:(id)sender { 

    float spanX = 0.00725;
    float spanY = 0.00725;

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    region.center.longitude = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = spanX;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = spanY;

    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animation sequence would be like this:

In that first animation block will ***slide/glide*** map to your specified location (let's say user location).

And then in completion block:

Another animation will ***zoom in/out*** to your location. Change values appropriate as your need.

```
- (void) showUserLocation {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{

        [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
            MKCoordinateSpan span;
            span.latitudeDelta  = 1;
            span.longitudeDelta = 1;

            MKCoordinateRegion region;
            region.span = span;
            region.center = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
            [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
        }];
    }];
}
```

Comment: cool thanks @Kampai that gave me the zoom down into animation type effect I was after but not the horizontal / vertical slide to location part of it. Eg. Say my MapView is showing China and my current location is in USA I'd like the view to slide from China across to USA, and then do the zoom down part like what you provided etc How do I do that first bit?

Comment: I tried your edited code @Kampai but no luck, it still just jumps straight to user location (no map slide from Country to Country effect etc) it starts off at the Zoomed in level and then after animateWithDuration:1.5 zooms out to the country region view

Comment: I have added one more animation block to show animation for zoom out to and I have tried this code it is working perfect. Please check that before calling this method you don't have set any region or span value for map (you don't need to) when you call this method.

Comment: thats awesome @Kampai thanks so much yeah I had a region/span value set in my - (IBAction)zoomToCurrentLocation:(id)sender method, as soon as I took it out it worked perfectly! I understand now, makes sense with the two animation blocks, thanks again!